# mySQL Self Join - inner join or join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

quick clarification. When joining contents from the same table, must I always declare join type as INNER?

For example,

```
SELECT p1.country_code,
       p1.size AS size2010,
       p2.size AS size2015
FROM populations AS p1
  INNER JOIN populations AS p2
    ON  p1.country_code = p2.country_code;
```

(on the table shown in this screenshot)

[image: y]

When I tried to remove the keyword INNER, it was wrong. Is it because JOIN does not exist in SQL?

Thanks and cheers.

Comment: JOIN without specifying the join type is a synonim of INNER JOIN. But specify join type is more safe. Do not save bytes... you can't use them anywhere anyway.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: *When I tried to remove the keyword INNER, it was wrong.* What "it"? The query itself or the result returned?

Comment: @akina, got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do want a self (inner) join here, but you are missing logic which limits each table to a certain year:

```
SELECT
    p1.country_code,
    p1.size AS size2010,
    p2.size AS size2015
FROM populations AS p1
INNER JOIN populations AS p2
    ON p1.country_code = p2.country_code
WHERE
    p1.year = 2010 AND
    p2.year = 2015;
```

Comment: Oh I see, why do i need the where clause specifying the years?

Comment: The logic of your join is to match two records having the _same_ country codes, but _different_ years (2010 from the first, 2015 from the second).

Comment: May i ask if this is the same as writing `SELECT
    p1.country_code,
    p1.size AS size2010,
    p2.size AS size2015
FROM populations AS p1
INNER JOIN populations AS p2
    ON p1.country_code = p2.country_code
AND
    p1.year =  p2.year - 5;`

Comment: @Rosellx Yes, it is logically the same because an inner join is being used.  If we were using a left join, then it would _not_ be the same.